# Solving a version of the liar paradox

Tags: logic, paradoxes

Given two people $Alice ,Bob$ are either lying or telling the truth Now suppose $Alice$ says "At least one of us is lying."

We have two cases:
$Alice$ is telling the truth $\implies$ $Bob$ is lying.
$Alice$ is lying, $Alice$ is lying about $\exists$ liar, thus $Bob$ must be telling the truth.
Now this is a familiar form of the liar paradox, and for homework I'm given 5 answer choices:
**(1)** Alice and Bob are either both liars or both say the truth.
**(2)** Alice and Bob are both liars
**(3)** Alice and Bob both say the truth
**(4)** Alice says the truth, Bob is a liar
**(5)** Alice is a liar, Bob says the truth

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Be precise. How do these X and Y characters relate to Alice and Bob? Also, you seem to have reasoned as if X said "at least one of us is lying". That's not what X said. Is there a "not" missing from your statement of the question?

Comment: @SteveJessop How would I do this for at least one?

Comment: I was getting to that, but I realised none of the presented answers is correct in that case. If X says "exactly one is telling the truth" then either that's true (X true, Y liar) or else it's false (X liar, Y therefore also liar to prevent X's statement being true). So all it would tell you is that Y's a liar, not what X does.

Comment: @SteveJessop it should read "at least one is a liar" my apologies

Comment: OK, now your reasoning goes: "X is lying, X is telling the truth" which is faulty :-) "At least one of us lying" cannot be a lie for the same reason that "I'm a liar" cannot be a lie. But it's different from "I'm a liar" in that it can be true.

Comment: @SteveJessop So $X$ is always telling the truth, but then what is $Y$? Always lying?

Comment: Since X is telling the truth and claims Y is lying yes, Y is lying.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thus **(4)** is our correct answer choice?

Comment: Depends which of Alice and Bob is X.

Comment: Alice is $X$, Bob is $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

The principle here is that

If x says  y then $ x \equiv y $ is true independent of if x is telling the truth or is lying.

So in your question  allice says "one of us is an liar"

"one of us is an liar" can be formulated as $ \lnot a \lor \lnot b $

The formula to test then becomes $ a \equiv (\lnot a \lor \lnot b) $
at that you can do with a truth table.

```
n | a | b | a <-> ( ~a v ~b)
1 | T | T |    F       F
2 | T | F |    T       T
3 | F | T |    F       T
4 | F | F |    F       T
```

Only in line 2 the formula is true so $Alice$ is telling the truth and $Bob$ is a liar.